# Timber pagination with custom Query gives me 404

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I am kinda a newbie at Wordpress. 
I've looked a lot on StackOverflow for a solution for this problem but none worked for me. 
I'm using Timber and ACF.

Here's the situation: I've made 4 custom post_type ( News, Products, Services and Places ). I've created a custom page for the news. (**page-news.twig** )

In my `page.php` file I've added a custom query like this:

```
global $paged;

if (!isset($paged) || !$paged) {
    $paged = 1;
}

$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = new TimberPost();
$context['post'] = $post;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'page' => $paged
);

$context['news'] = new Timber\PostQuery($args);
```

So I've set a maximum of posts for page, which is 3, and In my .twig file:

```
    {% for single_news in news %}
{% include['news.twig', single_news] %}
{% endfor %}

{% if news.pagination.prev %}
<a href="{{news.pagination.prev.link}}" class="prev {{ news.pagination.prev.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Prev</a>
{% endif %}

{% if news.pagination.next %}
<a href="{{ news.pagination.next.link}}" class="next {{ news.pagination.next.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Next</a>
{% endif %}
```

When I go to the news page, there are 3 posts per page ( correct ) and it displays me the `Next` anchor which is correct.
The problem is that the link brings me to `/news/page/2` that doesn't exists and gives me 404 error. I've tried many solutions like the pre_get_posts and none worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pagination only works on archive pages, but not on singular pages. See [The WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/) for what counts as an archive page.

This means that you can’t use **page.php** as your template file for displaying your news posts. You have two possibilities here:

1. You can use **archive.php**, or even **archive-news.php** if your Custom Post Type for news is named `news`.
2. If you’d use the default post type `post` for your news section, you could select the page where you want to display your posts archive. The template file to display your posts archive would then be **home.php**.

If you go for the first option, you need to make sure that when you register your post type (either through [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) or a plugin), you set the `public` option to `true` and that you set `has_archive` to `true` as well.

The problem with archive pages is that now you can’t use some editing functionalities that you normally have with pages. For an archive, you can’t set a title or add content with the editor like you’re used for pages. But if you use ACF, you can set up an [options page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/) where you add a select for your «Page for News». Name it `page_for_news` and then, in your template file, you can select the proper post that Timber should use on the archive page with

```
$post = new Timber\Post( get_field( 'page_for_news', 'option' ) );
```

This method practically replicates option 2 for Custom Post Types.

Also, a hint about your news post include in Twig:

```
{% for single_news in news %}
    {% include['news.twig', single_news] %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you do this, then Twig will try to find a **news.twig** template as well as a template named after `single_news`. But `single_news` is not a string here, but an instance of `Timber\Post`. So that doesn’t help you. You can use the following instead:

```
{% for single_news in news %}
    {% include 'news.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer. I migrated my page-news.php to archive-news.php, worked like a charm.