# Timber pagination with custom post type

Tags: pagination, custom-post-type, timber

I am trying to use the example shown in the Timber docs for [pagination with a custom post type](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/pagination/#what-if-i-m-not-using-the-default-query). This is not working as I'd expect.

The only way I've gotten a pagination to output is to add `query_posts($args);` after I set up my query `$args` and before I pass them into a new `Timber\PostQuery` but from everything I've read, I shouldn't be doing this.

I have read this [issue thread](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/841), but it seems to rely on using `WP_Query` directly, and I'm trying to keep this task as simple as possible.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can't see where this is documented, but this structure seems to have worked for me (calling `pagination()` on my CPT collection):

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'paged' => $paged
);
$myCollection = new Timber\PostQuery($args);
$context['collection'] = $myCollection;
$context['pagination'] = $myCollection->pagination();
```

Then I have to set up [`Routes::map`](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/routing/) for the pagination to actually work. Here's an example:

```
function add_routes() {
  Routes::map(':name/page/:pg', function($params){
    $query = 'posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&paged='.$params['pg'];
    Routes::load('template-'.$params['name'].'.php', $params, $query);
  });
}
```

I'm calling this function from the root of my `functions.php` (i.e., not using any hook).

I should note that this also allows me to still get the `page` in my context -- on every paginated page -- using `$post = new Timber\Post()`. The key there seems to be setting up the route with `posts_per_page=1` and `post_type=page`. Originally, I was confusing myself by setting up the route mapping the same as my query `$args` for paginated CPTs in my template.

Comment: In which PHP template file do you have the code where you call `$myCollection = new Timber\PostQuery($args);`?

Comment: This is a custom template, so, for example, I have `template-mycollection.php` and `page-mycollection.twig`.

Depending on how my `mycollection` CPT is setup (e.g., using a slug rewrite), the route would probably look like `www.mysite.com/mycollections`, and then further pages would have `/page/2`, etc.

Comment: This is the reason why the default is not working then. Paginations only work in native **archive pages**, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53248110/1059980). I have to admit this is not documented. It could definitely be improved!

Comment: @Gchtr, I had started to think about looking at the use of an archive page, but will have to decide whether this is acceptable for end users (may have to do with how the URL can or cannot be rewritten). I'm not a WP dev, so learning this as I go. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Gchtr, looking at your linked post, I will probably try out an implementation with a custom archive page and ACF for extra admin possibilities (this may not be acceptable as a plain archive page with no other editing capabilities).

Comment: @Gchtr, if you are still looking at this, I have a follow-up question. 

Having put together an archive page and removed the custom routing, I'm getting a 404 on my 3rd of 7 pages, using the `Timber\Pagination` object, out of the box.

I think the issue may be the fact that my CPT's name does not match the path (slug rewrite). I can add back the route definition and hardcode the `post_type` name, but can't get it from the slug, because the route definition is called before CPTs are initialized. 

Do you have any suggestions for how to make this work with less configuration / hardcoding?

Comment: It’s really strange that you get a 404 only on the 3rd page. I guess it should be possible to use the rewrite slug option to change the path of the archive page when you register a post type. I can’t remember if I ever used it that way with Timber, but I guess it should work. Make sure you save your permalinks in the settings to make sure the rewrite rules are flushed. If it doesn’t work, you can maybe open an issue in Timber with a reduced test case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the CPT slug rewrite works, and it is odd that I'm experiencing a 404 on the 3rd page. And, yes, whenever I change any of the values that affect permalinks, I visit that settings page to flush, and the changes clearly take effect. Anyway, my only solution so far has been to use a `Routes::map` definition. I refined it to work as a callback to `init`, even though this isn't advised, and at that point I can map over my custom post types and get the name to pass to the route instead of the slug. So, it's working, but it feels like I shouldn't need to do what I'm doing.

Comment: You definitely shouldn’t have to mix Pagination and Routing. But it’s really hard to tell what the problem might be. It could also be another plugin that you have installed. Can you deactivate all plugins and see if the error still exists? Otherwise, if you can create a reduced test case and you think that it’s a Timber issue, you can open a new issue in the [Timber repo](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues).

Comment: We are no longer having this issue. I believe the culprit was starting off by getting the pager value in our template (i.e., I've removed it). Per the instructions: `// now removed //global $paged; //if (!isset($paged) || !$paged) { $paged = 1; }` Too many changes to be sure, but at this point, pagination is working without any additional code outside of the template PHP.