# Getting custom post type data including ACF with Timber?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I need to get custom post type data for usage with Timber and Twig, it's working fine using the standard `WP_Query`, such as:

```
// Get the testimonials custom post type posts
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'perm' => 'readable',
    'nopaging' => true
);

$context['testimonials'] = new WP_Query( $args );

// Restore the global $post to the current post in the main query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

However this obviously doesn't get ACF fields.

Was going to do the below as indicated in the Timber docs:

```
// Get the testimonials custom post type posts
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'perm' => 'readable',
    'nopaging' => true
);

$context['testimonials'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );
```

However, it seems that `get_posts` is getting [deprecated in 2.0](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1957).

It seems like the best way to do it would be by using Timber's `PostQuery`, but because of lacking documentation I am unsure if it is more or less an encapsulation of `WP_query` and I can simply do something like:

```
// Get the testimonials custom post type posts
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'perm' => 'readable',
    'nopaging' => true
);

$context['testimonials'] = new PostQuery(array('query' => $args));
```

Am I on the right track here or what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402077/472501) and also digging through the code a bit I found out how to do it I believe:

```
// Get the testimonials custom post type posts
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'perm' => 'readable',
    'nopaging' => true
);

$query = new Timber\PostQuery($args);

// Get an array of post objects
$context['posts'] = $query->get_posts();
```

From what I can tell, all the respective `WP_Query` args seems to work using this method as well - but if you need pagination to work I would advise reading that other answer I linked to as it contains more information on that.

Comment: Timber contributor here. That looks perfectly fine! We’re actually not deprecating `Timber::get_posts()` in 2.0 after some back and forth. You can continue using `Timber::get_posts()`. However, if you need pagination as well, you need to use `Timber\PostQuery` in 1.x. Pagination will only work with `Timber::get_posts()` in 2.x.

Comment: @Gchtr Just to clarify, with pagination, you're saying if you want to use it in 1.x you need to use `Timber\PostQuery`, but in 2.x it only works in `Timber::get_posts()` ?

Answer (score 0):

ACF fields have some weird numerical keys in the database.  To get the data just use their own function
    get_fields();
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/

Comment: Thanks - I am familiar with using `get_field` etc, but not really the answer I am looking for here as I am wanting to get the data for all the fields returned in the initial response, just like it does when using `get_posts`.